# Bootstrap NavBar Alignment (3 Columns with Responsive Menu)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, css-position, navbar

I basically have a pretty simple question, but my portfolio will look better if I can make this simple addition.

I want my NavBar in bootstrap to be in 3 columns, essentially like the image I've mocked up below.

[image: A basic idea of what I need.]

I currently have the base bootstrap navBar setup with the default code like so:

```
<!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-white fixed-top">
  <div class="container">

    <a class="nav-link" href="#">my name goes here</a>      

    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">about</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">resume</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>
</nav>
```

I can make a weird version look right with messing with padding and stuff, but I dont want that. The hardest part for me is understanding the responsive version, and having the one link on the left (work) and two links on the right (about, resume) merge into one dropdown navigation and have the 'my name goes here' become the header above it on mobile.

Any help, or a point in the right direction would be great.

Also, it can be assumed my CSS is the base bootstrap CSS.

Thanks

**UPDATE**

```
<!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand-md bg-success justify-content-between">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".dual-nav">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse dual-nav w-50 order-1 order-md-0">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link pl-0" href="#">work <span class="sr-only">work</span></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <a href="/" class="navbar-brand mx-auto d-block text-center order-0 order-md-1 w-25">Colin Grant</a>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse dual-nav w-50 order-2">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="">about</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="">resume</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

This seems to work perfectly, any tips for makign it better?

Thanks

Comment: what version of bootstrap??

Comment: This is an absoutely perfect example of what I want.http://www.rachel-schmitz.com/

Comment: I mean bootstrap 4 or 3?? or that your question what version to use??

Comment: @לבנימלכה Bootstrap3

Comment: You rae using bootstrap 4 classes ! and saying you arte using bootstrap 3 .. how is that possible !

Comment: @CGKeaton  Nandita Arora Sharma is right you use code of bootstrap 4 and use bootstrap 3

Comment: Ah! A mistake, sorry it is Bootstrap4. Forgive me.

Answer (score 4):

Following is how I did it using bootstrap 4. When screen size is <992px right side of the navbar will collapse into a button.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg_color_primary sticky-top d-flex justify-content-between ">

    <div class="navbar-nav  col-4 align-items-start ">
        <div class="text-white bg_color_primary_light  rounded-circle p-2">
            Work
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-4  d-flex justify-content-center">
        <a class="navbar-brand text-white brand_name   " href="">
            BrandName
        </a>
    </div>

    <button class="  navbar-toggler ml-auto  align-items-end" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
            data-target="#navbarNavDropdown"
            aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse  col-4 " id="navbarNavDropdown">
        <div class="navbar-nav ml-auto ">
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="">About</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="">Resume</a>
        </div>
    </div>

</nav>
```